# Changing net use timeout

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, network-share

I have a script that runs against remote sites to map a drive and work with a file. I use `Test-Connection` to make sure the remote server is alive, then attempt to map the location needed with `net use`. My problem is that, depending on who runs the script a certain subset of remote locations is pingable, but cannot be mapped. Is there any way to make `net use` time out after a shorter time, or another way to do this with Windows 7 or 2008 commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is to probably figure out why they can not map the drive. To answer your question, net use does not have a time out command:

> C:\Users\user>net use /? The syntax of this command is:
>
> NET USE [devicename | *] [\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
>
> ```
>     [/USER:[domainname\]username]
>     [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
>     [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
>     [/SMARTCARD]
>     [/SAVECRED]
>     [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]
> ```
>
> NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME
>
> NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]

However if you want your script to keep on moving while your net use command figures it's self out you could use the `start` command to launch it in a new window and the normal script should be able to keep doing what ever you want it to do. `start net use \\\computername\sharename x:`

Comment: That's pretty much what I had determined, but I was hoping for a better answer. If no better answer pops up, I'll accept this one in a day or two.

Comment: @JoshuaNurczyk have you looked and how to map a network drive with GPO? Or would that not apply?

Comment: Unfortunately, it would not apply. It has to do with how the network is set up, and I have no way to fix it myself.

Answer (score 1):

start your Timer
run NET USE with "start" as supposed.
send your Batch into a loop

- check if the netshare is already connected.
- If yes Exit loop,
- if not check if timer has exceeded
- - if yes - Echo Error and exit
    Do what you want to do :)

Kind regards
Johannes